# Find a max value for each Range interval in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, max, vba

I have data in an Excel sheet that depict the quantity of various gases present at depth say d. So for each depth interval like from `3238.1 to 3238.9` i need to find the max value of all the gases columns (C1-C3, IC4,IC5,nC5, OC2).

For example for depth 3238 there are 9 interval (3238.1 to 3238.9) so i need to find the max value in all the gas columns like for column C1 max value for 3238 will be 5650.

Sometimes there are more than 10 intervals for a meter e.g `1338.1, 1338.2, ...up to 1338.15 etc` or sometimes less than 10, e.g, `1338.1,1338.3,1338.5,1338.6` etc because of missing data.

**INPUT:**

```
╔═══════╦════════╦══════╦═════╦═════╦═════╦═════╦═════╦═════╦══════╗
║       ║ Depth  ║   C1 ║  C2 ║ C3  ║ iC4 ║ nC4 ║ iC5 ║ nC5 ║ OC2  ║
╠═══════╬════════╬══════╬═════╬═════╬═════╬═════╬═════╬═════╬══════╣
║       ║ 3238.1 ║    0 ║ 125 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║ 1200 ║
║       ║ 3238.2 ║ 5601 ║  78 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║ 1600 ║
║       ║ 3238.3 ║ 5610 ║ 156 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║ 1588 ║
║       ║ 3238.4 ║ 5612 ║ 120 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║ 1900 ║
║       ║ 3238.5 ║ 5640 ║ 300 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║ 2100 ║
║       ║ 3238.6 ║ 5650 ║ 401 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║ 2648 ║
║       ║ 3238.7 ║ 5601 ║ 366 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║ 2841 ║
║       ║ 3238.8 ║ 5610 ║ 102 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║  450 ║
║       ║ 3238.9 ║ 5612 ║ 211 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║ 1800 ║
║       ║ 3239.0 ║  111 ║  20 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║ 1723 ║
║       ║ 3239.1 ║  121 ║  39 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║ 1646 ║
║       ║ 3239.2 ║   56 ║  12 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║ 1569 ║
║       ║ 3239.3 ║  214 ║   6 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║ 1492 ║
║       ║ 3239.4 ║  125 ║   9 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║ 1415 ║
║       ║ 3239.5 ║  300 ║   7 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║ 1338 ║
║       ║ 3239.6 ║  390 ║  14 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║ 3160 ║
║       ║ 3239.7 ║  312 ║  16 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║ 1523 ║
║       ║ 3239.8 ║  360 ║  18 ║   3 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║ 1634 ║
║       ║ 3239.9 ║  380 ║  19 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║ 4823 ║
║       ║ 3240.0 ║   80 ║   6 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║ 3065 ║
╚═══════╩════════╩══════╩═════╩═════╩═════╩═════╩═════╩═════╩══════╝
```

**Example OUTPUT:**

```
╔═══════╦══════╦═════╦════╦═════╦═════╦═════╦═════╦══════╗
║ Depth ║  C1  ║ C2  ║ C3 ║ iC4 ║ nC4 ║ iC5 ║ nC5 ║ OC2  ║
╠═══════╬══════╬═════╬════╬═════╬═════╬═════╬═════╬══════╣
║  3238 ║ 5650 ║ 401 ║  0 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║ 2841 ║
║  3239 ║  390 ║  39 ║  3 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║   0 ║ 4823 ║
╚═══════╩══════╩═════╩════╩═════╩═════╩═════╩═════╩══════╝
```

The data shows the quantity of various gases present at depth d.

I need to find the maximum for each meter interval (max for 3238.1 to 3238.9).

I tried using the Excel max function but was not able to achieve the desired output.

What is the best way to achieve this, which functions should I use or macros etc.

Comment: Done.!! Thanks Makah and pnuts.

Comment: Makah, i think the input data moved by one column, can you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use array formula `max(if())` to calculate max value over the range, matching criteria and `floor()` function to get rid of the decimal part:

```
=FLOOR(A2,1)
```

```
=MAX(IF(FLOOR($A$2:$A$21,1)=K2,$B$2:$B$21))
```

[image]